# Is this little Doctrine2 dynamic SQL enough safe of injection?

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

I kwnow that using an ORM like **Doctrine2 for building queries is safe**, meaning that  parameters are escaped by default.

But i'm guessing that this is not so obvious **when using literals** and when this literal comes directly from the query string:

```
    $builder = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // Loop each allowed filter field and check if exists in $request
    foreach($this->getFilterFields() as $filter) :

        // Skip falsy values in $request
        if(!$value = $request->get($filter)) continue;

        // Add OR LIKE %$value% where $value is GET paramter
        $like = $builder->expr()->literal("%$value%");
        $builder->orWhere($builder->expr()->like("e.$filter", $like));

    endforeach;
```

Should safety be improved in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$queryBuilder->expr returns an ExpressionBuilder object.  Inside ExpressionBuilder we find:

```
public function literal($input, $type = null)
{
    return $this->connection->quote($input, $type);
}
```

So literals do get quoted and should be fine to use.

We also find:

```
public function like($x, $y)
{
    return $this->comparison($x, 'LIKE', $y);
}
public function comparison($x, $operator, $y)
{
    return $x . ' ' . $operator . ' ' . $y;
}
```

$y is fine because it goes through literal first.  Do want to be a bit careful about $x.  As long as your filterFields are internal then no problem.  If they are coming from the user then you need to make sure they are valid.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, $this->getFilterFields() list all valid search field so any not valid argumetn will be ignored.